# Good ruby url shortener gems?

Tags: rubygems

What good, reliable ruby gems do you use for shortening URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many gems out there. It dependes on your need. Shortly gem provides many url shortener services(googl, bitly,...). Check that out.

Answer (score 0):

Please, see https://github.com/zigotto/googl for this.

It's simple ruby gem for Google URL Shortener API.